# How is Lancelot so strong, when he couldn't inherit the main sources of strength from his father?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the last *Nanatsu no Taizai* movie, Lancelot proves to be as strong or stronger than Tristan, they have a confrontation where we can see their strengths. But unlike Tristan, who could inherit his power from his demonic father and angelic mother, Lancelot couldn't inherit the main sources of power of his human father Ban.

Ban was insanely strong for 3 reasons, 1- He lived over 1100 years being immortal, so he could get stronger all those years. 2- He trained hundreds of years in the Purgatory 3- He has a magic power that allows him to steal power from others.

Lancelot doesn't have any of these 3 features. Then, how can Lancelot be so strong, when he couldn't inherit the main sources of strength from his father?

Comment: Read the side story. It hasn't been really revealed but an event took place in his childhood